# How to get exception details on shared error.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, exception, log4net

I am using ASPNet MVC4 with HandleErrorAttribute filter configured on Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

On my web.config I have configured customError mode to RemoteOnly:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

So, the user are redirected to ~/Shared/Error.cshtml when a exception are raised on any View, that`s ok.

Now, I can catch this exception for log:

~/Shared/Error.cshtml code:

```
@{
    log4net.LogManager
      .GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
      .Fatal("Not captured exception", ex);
}
```

Actually this code are working fine (without EX parameter), but I need to improve my log including exception details.

How I can get exception details on this page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend writing a custom handler and log within, e.g.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
public class HandleErrorAttributeCustom : HandleErrorAttribute
{

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
                base.OnException(context);
           log4net.LogManager
          .GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
          .Fatal("Not captured exception", context.Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to register the custom handle class, for instance with replacing `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` with `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttributeCustom());` in the `FilterConfig` class or the `Application_Start()` in the Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 10):

Just make your `Error.cshtml` view strongly typed to [`HandleErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which is the model being passed to this view by the HandleErrorAttribute:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    log4net
        .LogManager
        .GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
        .Fatal("Not captured exception", Model.Exception);
}
```

And by the way, logging inside a view doesn't seem like the cleanest thing you could do. I'd rather write my custom error handler attribute and log the exception there.

Comment: I tested your code and have worked great, this is also a correct answer. Since SO don't accept two answers, I have to choose dove's answer because avoid codding on View. +1 for you.